# GridView not working properly when scrolling

Tags: android, gridview, scroll, baseadapter

I have simple GridView with images. Each item in GridView has ImageView that shows the picture and another ImageView that becomes visible when image is favorited( white star).

When i scroll fast to the bottom of the GridView the Image that was favorited and selected on position 3 for instance is not selected and favorited anymore and instead some other item on the bottom becomes randomly selected and favorited. And then again when i scroll to top some other item becomes favorited and selected randomly.

But i noticed i have this problem mostly only with second and third item.

**This is originaly selected and favorited item :** 
[image: This is originaly selected and favorited item]

[image: And this item gets randomly selected and favorited at bottom when scrolled to bottom]

**And this item gets randomly selected and favorited at bottom when scrolled to bottom:**

My Adapter  :

```
    public class ImageAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return imageUrls.length;
    }


    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {

        return 0;

    }

    public class ViewHolder {
        ImageView imageView;
        ProgressBar progressBar;
        ImageView imgFavorite;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        final ViewHolder holder;


        if (convertView == null) {


            convertView = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.item_grid_image,
                    parent, false);
            holder = new ViewHolder();
            holder.imageView = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.image);
            holder.progressBar = (ProgressBar) convertView
                    .findViewById(R.id.Itemprogress);
            holder.imgFavorite = (ImageView) convertView
                    .findViewById(R.id.selectorText);
            convertView.setTag(holder);

            inflater = (LayoutInflater) getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);


            RelativeLayout relative = (RelativeLayout) convertView.findViewById(R.id.profileImageContainer);
            relative.getLayoutParams().height = width;

        } else {
            holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
        }

        imageLoader.displayImage(imageUrls[position], holder.imageView,
                options, new SimpleImageLoadingListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onLoadingStarted(String imageUri, View view) {
                        holder.progressBar.setProgress(0);
                        holder.progressBar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onLoadingComplete(String imageUri,
                            View view, Bitmap loadedImage) {
                        holder.progressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);

                    }
                }, null);


        if (profilePicList[position].isprofilepic && firstTime
                ) {
            currentPosition = position;
             DefaultImg = convertView;
             holder.imgFavorite.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
             firstTime = false;
        }


        return convertView;

    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int position) {
        return null;
    }

}
```

**EDIT: added on clicklistener code where i change background of selected image**

```
AdapterView.OnItemClickListener onItemClickListener = new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position,
            long id) {

        if(mActionMode == null) {
            mActionMode = startActionMode(mActionModeCallback);
        }




        if (previousView != null) {

            ((ViewGroup) previousView).getChildAt(0).setAlpha(1.0f);
            ((ViewGroup) previousView).setBackgroundResource(0);

        }

        ((ViewGroup) view).setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.back);
        ((ViewGroup) view).getChildAt(0).setAlpha(0.3f);

        previousView = view;


    }

};
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put else part, that might solve your problem. Gridview reuses each imageview when you scroll.

```
if (profilePicList[position].isprofilepic && firstTime
                ) {
            currentPosition = position;
             DefaultImg = convertView;
             holder.imgFavorite.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE); // or INVISIBLE
             firstTime = false;
 }else{
   holder.imgFavorite.setVisibility(View.GONE);
 }
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, but now the star doesn't show up at the bottom and the top when i slide back to the top.

Comment: its because you are using `firstTime` variable.What's the logic behind this if condition `if(profilePicList[position].isprofilepic && firstTime)` ?

Comment: Yeah you are correct, fixed the problem. Now star is always on its position now the only problem is selector. I select images with  AdapterView.OnItemClickListener and change background like this :  ((ViewGroup) view).setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.back); Any tips on fixing this?

Comment: in else part do, `((ViewGroup)view).setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.front);`

Comment: I don't think you understand me completly. i change background  of selected image in onclicklistener. To favorite image you don't just selected you must press a button. Please look my edited answer i posted on click listener code too.

Comment: `imageLoader.displayImage()` is setting image as source image not as background image. In onclick you are setting it as background image `((ViewGroup) view).setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.back);`. Use `imageView.setImageDrawable(context.getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.back));`

Comment: For background im not changing background of imageView but background of RelativeLayout. So when you click on some image relative layout  background of that image will change to light green. Is changing background in onClickListener wrong or should i try to change it in getView() ?

Comment: Yes,you also have to write it inside getview().ie, `if(favorited){change background and rest} else{ revert background and remove fav }`

Answer (score 1):

The adapters are built to reuse Views, when a View is scrolled so that is no longer visible, it can be used for one of the new Views appearing. This reused View is the convertView.

Add this bloc after your if condition (when you passe the imgFavorite to VISIBLE)

```
else 
{
   holder.imgFavorite.setVisibility(View.GONE);
   firstTime = true;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for help but it doesn't work as it is supposed to. Now the star doesn't show up at the bottom and the top when i slide back to the top.

Comment: Your condition in if statement should be initialized. 
Try my edited answer.

Comment: Yea i fixed the favorite image problem but now selection still gets randomly chosen. Please look my edited answer i added listener code.